# Print contents of lines up to a specific character

Tags: bash, perl, shell, awk, sed

how to print line until specific **last** character `-` , using sed or awk or perl one liners:

Given this input:

```
Kernel release..............2.6.18-194.26.1.el5-PAE
Master disk release.........swp-RedHat-Linux-OS-5.5.0.0-03
```

The requested output is:

```
Kernel release..............2.6.18-194.26.1.el5
Master disk release.........swp-RedHat-Linux-OS-5.5.0.0
```

Comment: did you get anything from [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187889/how-do-i-replace-the-last-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string-using-sed) post? `sed 's/\(.*\)-.*/\1/'` derived from @jimmiji's post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`sed` does it quite quickly:

```
$ sed 's/-[^-]*$//' file
Kernel release..............2.6.18-194.26.1.el5
Master disk release.........swp-RedHat-Linux-OS-5.5.0.0
```

This finds the last `-` followed by any number of non `-` characters up to the end of the line. Then, it replaces them with the empty string, so that they are removed.

Although an idiomatic `awk` solution is also nice:

```
$ awk -F- 'NF--' file
Kernel release..............2.6.18 194.26.1.el5
Master disk release.........swp RedHat Linux OS 5.5.0.0
```

This sets the field separator to `-` and decrements the number of fields in `1`. This works just if you have one `-`. Otherwise, the lines format would work (`-` would convert into space. For this, you would need to say `awk -F- -v OFS=- 'NF--' file`.

And you can also play with `rev` and `cut`:

```
$ rev file | cut -d- -f2- | rev
Kernel release..............2.6.18-194.26.1.el5
Master disk release.........swp-RedHat-Linux-OS-5.5.0.0
```

`rev` reverses the line, so that then we can get from the 2nd `-` on. Finally, we reverse back to get the initial format.

Through `python3`:

```
$ python3 -c 'import fileinput
with fileinput.input() as f:
    for line in f:
        print("-".join(line.split("-")[:-1]))' file
Kernel release..............2.6.18-194.26.1.el5
Master disk release.........swp-RedHat-Linux-OS-5.5.0.0
```

*`fileinput.input()` gets the input from standard input. `for line in f:` iterates over each line and then it splits the line according to `-` and then joins the splitted items with `-` as a delimiter by excluding the last splitted item.* [Credits to Avinash Raj!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28834287/linux-print-line-until-specific-last-character/28834318#comment45939153_28834318)

Comment: Ah, I was somehow thinking "first -"

Comment: @fedorqui what about python? I think most linux distributions has python pre-installed.

Comment: @AvinashRaj you are missing Ruby, c, Java and Haskell :-D I am not experienced enough with Python, so I guess I would decrease the quality of the answer by adding such approach.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I would be more than pleased to learn from you, so please go ahead!

Comment: identation is very important in python. `fileinput.input()` gets the input from  standard input. `for line in f:` iterates over each line and then it splits the line according to `-` and then join the splitted items with `-` as delimiter by excluding the last splitted item.

Comment: @AvinashRaj thanks a lot! I included your explanation in the answer as well :)

Comment: This is a job for sed. I expect you'll be hearing from seds union rep any day now with a cease and desist for those other solutions :-). The awk solution will only work in some awks, btw, e.g. neither nawk nor /usr/xpg4/bin/awk would support it.

Answer (score 4):

With `bash`:

```
while read; do echo "${REPLY%-*}"; done < infile
```

Output:

```
Kernel release..............2.6.18-194.26.1.el5
Master disk release.........swp-RedHat-Linux-OS-5.5.0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

with grep

```
grep -oP '.*(?=-)' file
```

with perl

```
perl -nE '/(.*)-/ and say $1' file
```

See also @G.Cito

Comment: + but the perl can be shortened since it will print only the match :-)

Comment: @G.Cito,  you mean `perl -nE 'say /(.*)-/ '  ` ?

Comment: yeah I posted it ;-) wheee!

Answer (score 2):

Loop through with an implicit `while(){}` and `say` what matches:

```
perl -nE 'say /(.*)-/' kernelverstion-data.txt
```

See [`perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

Comment: + Sorry I commented before I see your answer :-)